# Two window interface in java?

Tags: java

I want to design the interface of a chess game, such that the chess game is within the internal frame(window) and the external frame should have a file and settings menu bar and a background image only.

The user should use new game, save game , and undo from the file(menu bar). I have written the game code but cannot figure out that type of interface. Can anybody here help me how to figure it out? I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

- Add a `JDesktopPane` to the `MainFrame`. You can add a background to it.
- Use a `JInternalFrame` for gameboard frame.
- When use click new game from the `JMenuItem`, an `actionPerformed` should add the `JInternalFrame` to the `JDesktopPane` and make the `JInternalFrame` visible

---

If you don't understand how to create an interface at all, you should take a look at the [Swing tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

Specifically, have a look at

- How to Make Frames
- How to Use Internal Frames
- How to use DesktopPane
- How to use Menus
- How to write listeners.

If you understand the above fore-mentioned things, an you want a quick solution, look into a GUI Builder tool like Netbeans GUI Builder. If you don't understand the above concepts, I suggest you learn to hand code before working with auto-generated code, as it might overwhelm you.

Comment: I recon when i was new to Java, that i found these tuts complicated and hard to read. I would also suggest to check some video tutorials for total beginners. (for example thenewboston channel in youtube has some good beginner's tuts for swing )

Answer (score -1):

One way is for the external frame/JFrame to keep a reference to the internal JFrame, and in the external frame's ActionListeners, you can then call upon the internal/game frame's public getters, setters and various methods to change the game's settings or read the current game state. Figuring out the details of how to do this is the fun part!